# How to check if a row in a table has muti-byte characters in it in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, encoding

I have a table which has column of `descr` which stores string values. Some of the values in `descr` has multi-byte characters in it and I want to know all those rows so I can remove those characters. How can I query the tables using MySQL functions to determine which rows have multi-byte characters. I am using MySQL version 5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(descr) <> LENGTH(descr)
```

char_length is multi-byte aware and returns the actual character count. Length() is a pure byte-count, so a 3-byte char returns 3.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help. Now I need to figure out how to display them in Mysql since the default charecter set on Mysql is Latin1

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the collation and CHARSET functions on your descr column?

You can find the description of this functions here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html

I think for your need it fits better the COERCIBILITY function. You can do something like:

```
 select COERCIBILITY(descr, COLLATE utf8) from myTable;
```

and if this function returns 0 then you must edit the line.

Comment: No I have not and I have no clue how to use them ?

Comment: select charset(descr) from myTable;